# How-To safely clear variables in Named function after each process block iteration

Tags: function, powershell

I have a function with conditional statements that are based on the existence of a variable property having been created, rather than what the variable is.

What are some ways to safely ensure that for each iteration of the process block of the named function that the variables are discarded. So that each pass of an object through the process block can create the variables each time.

```
Function TestFunction {
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$PipelineValue
)
Process {

#PipelineValue may or may not have a property 1 or a property 2 
#depending on Computerlocation so the variable the must be discarded 
#each pass, or an upcoming object that passes through will eventually 
#evaluate true for both conditional statements.

$Selection = Switch ($PipelineValue.ComputerLocation) {
    "Moon" {[PsCustomObject]@{Property1 = "Moon_$($Pipelinevalue)."}}
    "Earth" {[PsCustomObject]@{Property2 = "Earth_$($Pipelinevalue)."}}
    }

if ($Selection.property1){
"Do This"
     }

if ($Selection.property2){
"Do That"
      }

}
```

I think Remove-Variable would work, but maybe nesting the innards of the process block in an unnamed function would be safer? Is it better to rely on how the property of functions in powershell works or to be more explicit?

This is a simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

I have the below in my `$Profile` which allows me to clear any variables I create after launch.

```
function Remove-UserVariable {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param ()
    if ($StartupVars) {
        $UserVars = Get-Variable -Exclude $StartupVars -Scope Global
        foreach ($var in $UserVars) {
            try {
                Remove-Variable -Name $var.Name -Force -Scope Global -ErrorAction Stop
                Write-Verbose -Message "Variable '$($var.Name)' has been removed."
            }
            catch {Write-Warning -Message "An error has occured. Error Details: $($_.Exception.Message)"}           
        }
    } else {Write-Warning -Message '$StartupVars has not been added to your PowerShell profile'}    
}

$StartupVars = @()
$StartupVars = Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

After this, running `Remove-UserVariable` would remove all variables declared AFTER the bottom two lines while also throwing out errors if you have messed anything up.

Hint: use the `-Verbose` param and it will tell you variable has been removed.